# Conversion from STL vector of subclass to vector of base class

Tags: c++, oop, stl, vector, polymorphism

I am wondering if it is possible to convert a vector of derived class values to a vector of base class values.  Specifically I want to be able to pass a vector of base class objects to a function whose formal parameters takes a vector of base class.  It does not appear to be possible directly as the following code example produces an error (using g++):

```
#include <vector>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
};


void function(std::vector<A> objs) {
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<B> objs_b;
    objs_b.push_back(B());
    function(objs_b);
}
```

> test.cc:16: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<B, std::allocator<B> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> >’ requested

I would like to be able to be able to call function without having to define a new vector with elements of type A, inserting my elements of type B or changing to a vector of pointers.

Comment: What about using a templates?

Comment: @GWW Yup templates are the answer, thanks.

Comment: How about passing a pointer to the vector. I've not done much work with vectors, but couldn't you pass a pointer to vector<b>. Could it be that simple?

Comment: baash: not that easy, sorry. vector<b>* isn't convertible to vector<a>* in the same way that vector<b> isn't a vector<a>.

Comment: "I would like to be able to be able to call function without having to define a new vector with elements of type A, inserting my elements of type B". Important: do not do this, this will not work. The runtime type of elements of `vector<A>` is always `A`. If you try to insert a subclass object into the vector, it will get sliced to `A` anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not. `vector<B>` is not derived from `vector<A>`, regardless of the fact that `B` is derived from `A`. You will have to change your function somehow.

A more idiomatically C++ approach might be to template it and have it take a pair of iterators - this is why the various standard library functions (`<algorithm>` etc) work that way, because it separates the implementation of the algorithm from the kind of thing it's operating on.

Comment: How would templates be implemented in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes there are ways around this.  Take a loot at Boost and some of the template meta-programming packages they have or use.  Specifically I'd look at [is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) for these kinds of purposes combined with partial template specialization.

For instance, if you wish to do some template magic trickery:

```
template<typename T, bool Allowed>
struct TemplateVectorCode;
```

You make a forward declaration of a templated class.  Then you make a specialization with a "true" boolean value:

```
template<typename T> struct TemplateVectorCode<T, true>{
    void operator(const std::vector<T>& myVector) const{ //definition in here }
};
```

Finally you use that with `is_base_of` to only instantiate instances of your template functor in the following manner:

```
template<typename T, typename Base>
struct MyFunction : TemplateVectorCode<T, boost::is_base_of<Base,T>::value>{
};
```

The important point to note is that since we have not defined a `TemplateVectorCode<T, false>` the compiler will throw a compile error if you attempt to use your functor with a class type `T` that does not derive from the type `V`.  That means you can work with the same code in one place without having to write multiple versions of it.

(if I screwed up the partial template specialization, someone please edit it.  I need to go to bed.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make your function accept standard vectors of any child classes of a given type (in this case, class A) using templates in C++14.

```cpp
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, bool> = true>
void function(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    // implemenation
}

std::vector<A> vec_a;
std::vector<B> vec_b;
function(vec_a); // ok
function(vec_b); // ok
```