# Templated data types with derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say I have the following:

```
class Base 
{
  protected:
    Base() { }
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
};
```

Now suppose I do this with a template:

```
TemplatedClass<Base> *generic = new TemplatedClass<A>();
```

It doesn't work, and I believe I understand why, but I'd like to know if I can do something equivalent. I have several template specializations of the form

```
typedef TemplatedClass<A> ASpec;
typedef TemplatedClass<B> BSpec;
typedef TemplatedClass<C> CSpec;
```

I have a single variable whose type I'd like to defer until runtime, so that I can dynamically assign it like

```
if(condition1)
  generic = new ASpec();
else if(condition2)
  generic = new BSpec();
```

Is there any way to go about this? I don't have the ability to change the fact that the classes are templated and not inheriting from a base class, or I'd just do that.

Comment: where is `TemplatedClass` defined?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. There is no template named `TemplatedClass`. Nobody's going to guess what this template does.

Comment: TemplatedClass represents a made-up class template for the purposes of this question. Pretend for a moment that I replaced TemplatedClass with std::vector. My question is less about the specific code I wrote and more about whether or not the assignment would ever be valid for *any* template specialization.

Comment: For `std::vector`, no. For some other template, maybe. It depends on the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in C++.
The fact that `A` derives from `Base` doesn't mean that `TemplatedClass<A>` derives from `TemplatedClass<Base>`.

See this Stack Overflow post for alternatives:
[Conversion from STL vector of subclass to vector of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698023/conversion-from-stl-vector-of-subclass-to-vector-of-base-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can derive `TemplatedClass<T>` from `TemplatedClass<Base>`, either by specialising if for `Base`, or by providing a dummy class like this:

```
struct Dummy {};

template <typename T>
struct BaseClass<T> {
  typedef TemplatedClass<Base> Type;
};

template <>
struct BaseClass<Base> {
  typedef Dummy Type;
};

template <typename T>
struct TemplatedClass : BaseClass<T>::Type
{
  //...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Angew. If I were able to change things at that level, this is the way I'd go, but I have to work with TemplateClass as it's been defined.